# select a file without browsing using javascript

Tags: javascript

My main program prompts the user to browse for a file in order to convert it using ffmpeg. This is the format of the file browsing:

```
 <div>
      <p class="lead">1. Select audio file for conversion ( mp3, wma):</p>
       <div class="quick-center">
       <div class="quick-drop-outer quick-left"><input id="inFile" type="file" id="inputFile"/></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is the code where to launch the file and convert it according to selection: not whole code supported because no need of file conversion:

```
 document.getElementById('inFile').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
 function readInputFile(file) {
      // disable conversion for the time of file loading
      $('#convert').attr('disabled', 'true');

      // load file content
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('#convert').removeAttr('disabled');
          fileName = file.name;

          fileBuffer = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  }
 function handleFileSelect(event) {
      var files = event.target.files; // FileList object

      // files is a FileList of File objects. display first file name
      file = files[0];
      console.log(file);
      if (file) {
          $("#drop").text("Drop file here");
          readInputFile(file);


      }
  }
```

now, here is my problem, what I want to do is to upload the file directly from a selected folder (upload) where the audio files are already there. I want instead of browsing for the file, I want the last file in the upload folder to be uploaded instead of "inFile" so that conversion can happen.
how could that happen.
edit: A small brief about my project. the user records his voice using HTML5 and the link of that audio is uploaded using ajax and php into a folder named upload.what I simply want is instead of browsing that file, I want to write down the path of the file in the selected folder automatically once recording is done for conversion.so, instead of dropping the file by user, the file would be dropped and conversion starts from there.
help please.Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't have access to the filesystem with javascript, so you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

From JavaScript You dont have access to files and directories on host system.

Why?

Because is **VERY IMPORTANT SECURITY** feature to block reading Your disc for files from scripts.

Comment: I edited my question in a way more explaining how my project works and what is requested please if you can read what is required again.thank you for your help in advance

Comment: note that the folder is not local it's created by the program not on the localHost